# c# ThreadPool using less threads than cores because of memory restrictions with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, filesystemwatcher

I have an extensive image calculation task which uses about 1GB of memory (one calculation cycle takes about 4 seconds). I process those images automatically when they arrive in the folder using a FileSystemWatcher. When the FileSystemWatcher fires an event for a new file I queue the work in the eventhandler method with:

```
private void OnNewFileInDir(object source, FileSystemEventArgs evtArgs)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ProcessTheNewImage), evtArgs.FullPath); 
}
```

My problem is that the program crashes on a regular basis when the files arrive quickly. In the debug window I can see that neary 3GB memory are used in that moment. When I use smaller images in order to use less memory, there are no crashes (so far).

My question: What can I do to use less (maybe just 2) threads independent of cores of my computer?

Or is my approach of using a FileSystemWatcher to cue new files to a thread pool completely stupid? I am not at all experienced with thread races or similar things.
So, furthermore: Does that look threadsafe?

Thanks a lot upfront and all the best

Tim

For completeness here is the code executed by the threads (a bit simplified for ease of reading):

```
private void ProcessTheNewImage(object threadFilenameInfo)
{
   String filename = (String)threadFilenameInfo;

   // Load the image
   Image currentImage = Image.FromFile(filename);

   //Calculate the image in an external DLL
   Image currentResultImage = ImageProcessing.getResultImage(currentImage);

   //Create the filename with the result infos
   string saveFileName = "blahblah";

   //Save the image
   currentResultImage.Save(saveFileName);

   //dispose the images
   currentImage.Dispose();
   currentResultImage.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: How does it crash? With an OutOfMemoryException? If so, you could try compiling it as 64 bit.

Comment: Hey, sorry for not beeing clear: It crashed without any exception. Just this little window opens..."Program xzy does not work anymore" or what it says in english (in german: "xyz funktioniert nicht mehr")

Comment: The situation you describe looks like an unhandled exception. If you put try/catch in `ProcessTheNewImage()` it would show you which one.

Comment: I tried it with the try/catch and it's still the same. The little window appears. Maybe it s because I'm using an external (unmanged) DLL for the image processing. I modified my code to use a certain number of tasks (see Henk's answer) and that worked well for up to 2 tasks. Nevertheless thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Threadpool has only a very limited form of resource management. It will slowly keep adding threads when the queue fills up. It is meant for relatively small (< 500 ms) jobs. There is no safety-valve to stop it from clogging up your application.

You could create a workflow for this: the watcher event pushes simple datapackets into a ConcurrentQueue and then you create 2 or more Threads (better: Tasks) to process the queue. This will allow you to tune the number of threads.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Good to now that! I have read that the ThreadPool is for "short" jobs, but I thougth 4 seconds is short :)! I will try it with 2 or 3 tasks which looks in a list or tuple of filenames with and a marker if they are already processed. Or is there a better way with zhe concurrent queue? What exacly is a concurrent queue?

Comment: `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue` or maybe use a BlockingCollection (a Producer/Consumer wrapper around that Queue)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I modified my code now and it seems to be very stable for up to 2 tasks for the large images. Using smaller images I can use a lot more tasks running at the same. Basically I used an array of tasks. The lenght of the array defines the multithreading for my code. I use a separate thread which constantly looks into the `ConcurrentQueue` (which is filled by the `FileSystemWatcher`) and starts a new task for the next filepath when a slot in the array is free or a task in the array has been finished. In this moment the to be processed filepath is de-queue from the queue.